# Server in replset is not part of the specified setName

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Nodejs, Mongoose

I try to connect to mongolab.

```
mongoose.main_conn =        mongoose.createConnection(uriUtil.formatMongoose('
mongodb://USER:PASS@blabla-a0.mongolab.com:61804,
blabla-a1.mongolab.com:61804/database?replicaSet=rs-blabla'));
```

But I get an error:
Server in replset blabla is not part of the specified setName blabla

And

```
    MongoError: provided setName for Replicaset Connection does
 not match setName found in server seedlist
```

BTW, I can connect to mongodb://USER:PASS@url.mongolab.com:61374/database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in "uriUtil.formatMongoose", it works without.

Comment: Hi, How did you fixed this issue. I am using mongoose node js module.